# Transferring Apps from 10.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I was using edubuntu 10.04 and now I had Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. I found many of the apps in edubuntu useful, and I would like to know if it's possible to transfer all that apps to 16.04. I had uninstalled edubuntu and then installed Ubuntu 16.04, but fortunately one of my friend still have 10.04 in his PC. So... Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would much easier to install those apps from the internet. There's a big difference between 10.04 and 16.04. Many of those apps may have newer versions which work in 16.04, but which may not work on the old 10.04. Why use old software instead of newer one?

Install ubuntu-edu-tertiary in 16.04 by opening a Terminal window and type:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-tertiary`

Comment: is there anyway that i could install ubuntu-edu-tertiary package via terminal ?

Comment: @JovelS2000: See the last part of my answer.